# CSS can only apply for particular URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

CSS will only apply for particular URL link : http://localhost:53406/. If I change it to another port, the CSS formatting doesn't work. Why does it appear differently?

I'm working with ASP.net Core 2.0 / C#.

Thx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s36j8.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/misEy.png)

Comment: Hi Simon, welcome to Stack Overflow - could you please put your code into your post please?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C-h0zkqCB1iScS9wPBQ7NHyyqj5KTn2k